# Does 6-methyl-2-(methylamino)pyrimidin-4-ol show aromaticity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

[image: Compound]

Does this structure show aromaticity? Or does this not work with nitrogen?

Comment: Mm, oxygen radicals... is that an OH group?

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. That's an OH group

Comment: What's wrong about nitrogen? Pyridine is aromatic, so is pyrimidine, hence so should be your compound, once you fix that issue with O.

Answer (score 3):

Each Nitrogen has 5 valence electrons. They are using 2 of those in sigma bonds to their neighbouring atoms, 2 in an sp2 lone pair in the plane of the ring, leaving only 1 electron to contribute to the delocalised pi system.

Each carbon is also contributing 1 electron to the delocalised pi system, and has 3 involved in sigma bonds.

This means each member of your 6 membered ring is contributing 1 electron, 6 in total. This means it is aromatic, as all 3 bonding orbitals are fully occupied.